# It is possible to chain search & replace operations? (phpStorm)

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm

I have text and tables in a word-document and need to extract this into a website. It is very time-consuming to manually copy the table and write all the html.

**So I started to use some search & replace operations**. Like replace `\n` with `</td></tr>`. At the end I have like 5 different search & replace operations. Is there a way to chain these? I tried the **macro functionality** of PHPStorm but this doesn't work (does not support clicks on dialogs)

Anyone out there could help we with this or if not possible, recommend another tool that works on Mac OS X?

Thanks in advance

Comment: word has save as html option

Comment: I think php has ability to pass arrays of regex and replacements to its preg_ functions.

Comment: @Dagon: Did you ever take a look at this output? I'm not sure if cleaning all this microsoft-code saves time…

Comment: there are tools in php and other laguages to clean the horrible html of word. tidy for example:http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend @sln's suggestion, or you can chain regexes together in JavaScript. :-)

Also, might I recommend using my custom-built [regex tester](http://www.aiforvideogames.com/re) that will let you search/replace in sequence, but really it's nothing more than a fancy UI on top of preg_replace. :-)